# DNS target domain.com.herokudns.com is not usable

Tags: curl, heroku

I have never successful used `sub.mydomain.com.herokudns.com`.

I created an app on heroku, and then add `sub.mydomain.com` as custom domain to the app. Then heroku tell me to use this dns target: 
`sub.mydomain.com.herokudns.com`

Is it a CNAME or what? Doesn't looklike a valid cname:

I test this with curl:

`curl -v -H "Host: sub.mydomain.com" https://sub.mydomain.com.herokudns.com`, it never works.

This, however, works:

`curl -v -H "Host: sub.mydomain.com" https://myapp.herokuapp.com`

What's a confusion. Why does heroku even bother tell me about `sub.mydomain.com.herokudns.com` that have no use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does work, try doing:

`curl -v -H "Host: sub.mydomain.com" sub.mydomain.com.herokudns.com`

What you need to do to setup `sub.mydomain.com` to work with your app is to provide a CNAME through your DNS provider with the name set to `sub.mydomain.com` and Value set to `sub.mydomain.com.herokudns.com`.